# Change array I pass to function without Return in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, avr, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

This is my function:

```html
void eeprom_read_page(unsigned int address, unsigned char lengh, unsigned char *data[40])
{
    //unsigned char data[lengh] , i;
    unsigned char  i;
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(EEPROM_BUS_ADDRESS_W);
    i2c_write(address>>8);          //high byte address
    i2c_write(address*0xff);        //low byte address
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(EEPROM_BUS_ADDRESS_R);
    for(i=0 ; i<(lengh-1) ; i++)
    {
       *data[i+4]=i2c_read(1);
    }
    *data[lengh+3]=i2c_read(0);
    i2c_stop();
}
```

And this is how I use it somewhere in my code:

```html
eeprom_read_page(   ( (rx_buffer1[1]*256)+rx_buffer1[2] ) , rx_buffer1[3] , &tx_buffer1 );
```

And this is my array define:

```html
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE1 40
char rx_buffer1[RX_BUFFER_SIZE1],tx_buffer1[RX_BUFFER_SIZE1];
```

but `tx_buffer1` doesn't get values I give in data[]. I want to change `tx_buffer1` but don't use return. Any help?

Comment: Show how the array is defined.

Comment: Unsigned char *data[40] is an array of forty char*. Shouldn’t it be unsigned char data[40] or unsigned char *data?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Updated!

Comment: @barny I tried, but I get IDE error for both.

Comment: To change a parameter without a return, you need to modify a pointer.  That's your clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array declared the following way

```
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE1 40
char rx_buffer1[RX_BUFFER_SIZE1],tx_buffer1[RX_BUFFER_SIZE1];
```

used in the expression

```
&tx_buffer1
```

makes the expression type `char ( * )[RX_BUFFER_SIZE1]`.

At the same time the corresponding function parameter

```
unsigned char *data[40]
```

has the type `unsigned char **` because the compiler implicitly adjusts a parameter having an array type to pointer to an object of the element type of the array.

And moreover the function parameter uses the specifier unsigned char while the array declared with the specifier char.

So the function call is invalid. There is no implicit conversion between the pointer types.

There is no any sense to pass the array to a function by reference because in any case arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.

If you want to pass the array by reference to know its size in the function then the function parameter shall be declared like

```
char ( *data )[40]
```